# Move all files in subdirectories of a specific name up one directory level

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I've run a batch process to resize and optimize all images within a directory and subdirectories. Unfortunately, Photoshop CC doesn't have an option (that I'm aware of) to overwrite the existing images and instead creates a 'JPEG' directory anywhere it processes images and writes the processed images there. The number of images is relatively large (~2000 images) and they're divided into hundreds of subdirectories, so manually moving the images to overwrites the existing ones is out of the question.

How can I move all of the processed images in the 'JPEG' directories up a level to overwrite the original images? The closes I think I've come is this:

```
find . -type d -name "JPEG" -exec cd {} \; && find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec mv -v {} ..  \;
```

...but that drops all the images a level up from my current directory.

Can some one sort me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cd` only affects a subprocess which changes to the directory and dies, while its parent process remains unaffected.

Anyway, switching to a directory is rarely necessary or useful; just use the path directly in the `mv` command.

```
find . -type d -name "JPEG" -exec mv -v {}/*.jpg {}/..  \;
```

(Not in a place where I can test right now, but I guess the wildcard needs a shell, too:

```
find . -type d -name "JPEG" -exec sh -c 'mv -v {}/*.jpg {}/..'  \;
```

Untested, obviously.)

Comment: That's done it. The wildcard does need a shell, otherwise it won't work (I had previously tried the first command). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

backup your image directory before using the following script.

```
CURRENT_DIR=$(pwd)
for x in $(find -type d -name 'JPEG')
do
    cd $x && mv -v *.jpg ..  # you can use `cp` instead of `mv`, then remove JPEG directory.
    cd $CURRENT_DIR
done
```